# python psycopg2 conditional insert statements

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to write an INSERT statement that first checks to see if the data already exists. The current code is inside python using psycopg2 to connect to a postgresql db:

```
    sql = """IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table \  
         WHERE col_1 = (%s) AND col_2 = (%s) ) \
         INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)      \
         VALUES (%s, %s);"""
    data = ( col1_data, col2_data, col1_data, col2_data)
    try:
        CURSOR.execute(sql, data)
        DB.commit()
    except:
        print "Cursor failed INSERT INTO table.\n"
```

which does not work (and I haven't done quality error handling so I don't get any good information).
So, I went into psql and tried just:

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE c1=d1 AND c2=d2)
        INSERT INTO t (c1, c2) VALUES (d1,d2);
```

and I got the following error:

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF" 
    LINE 1: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = d1...
            ^
```

So I BELIEVE my error is in the sql not the python (though I could be wrong) since this works:

```
    sql = """INSERT INTO t2 (col_0, col_1, col_2) \
             VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"""
    data = (d1, d2, time.time())
    try:
        CURSOR.execute(sql, data)
        DB.commit()
    except:
        print "Cursor failed to INSERT INTO t2.\n"
```

For table 1, my CREATE was:

```
    db=> CREATE TABLE table (
    col_0 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    col_1 varchar(16),
    col_2 smallint
    );
    NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "pm_table_ip_id_seq" for serial column "pm_table.ip_id"
    NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "pm_table_pkey" for table "pm_table"
    CREATE TABLE
```

I am grateful for any help and guidance.

Comment: Are you sure those two columns can't compose the primary key?

Answer (score 1):

I used [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/plpgsql.html) for such a requirement in my project

```
insert_function = """
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION insert_if_unique (sql_insert TEXT)
    RETURNS VOID
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sql_insert;
    RETURN;
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    RETURN;
        -- do nothing
END;
$$;
"""

cursor.execute(insert_function);
```

You can use something like below to use it:

```
cursor.execute("insert_if_unique("+sql+")"%data)
```

The above query is not parameterized. So please be wary of SQL injection if you are getting the input from an external source.

**Note**: You can use `cursor.mogrify()` to evade SQL injection attacks.

```
sql = cursor.mogrify(sql,data)
cursor.execute("insert_if_unique("+sql+")")
```

Comment: need clear elabration, e.g. +sql+ means?

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing those. NOT EXISTS condition with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO t (c1, c2) VALUES (d1,d2)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE c1=d1 AND c2=d2)
```